# A curious fact on partitions of 7 integer and related question.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's start writing $7$ partitions, marking them with $n\ A$, where $n$ is a number of terms in partition and $A$ is a set of terms in it.

$$\underbrace {7}_{1\ \{7\}} = 7$$

$$\underbrace {6 + 1}_{2\ \{1,6\}} = 7$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {5 + 2}_{2\ \{2,5\}} = 7\ '}$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {5 + 1 + 1}_{3\ \{1,5\}} = 7\ '}$$

$$\underbrace {4 + 3}_{2\ \{3,4\}} = 7$$

$$\underbrace {4 + 2 + 1}_{3\ \{1,2,4\}} = 7$$

$$\underbrace {4 + 1 + 1 + 1}_{4\ \{1,4\}} = 7$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {3 + 3 + 1}_{3\ \{1,3\}} = 7\ '}$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {3 + 2 + 2}_{3\ \{2,3\}} = 7\ '}$$

$$\underbrace {3 + 2 + 1 + 1}_{4\ \{1,2,3\}} = 7$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1}_{5\ \{1,3\}} = 7\ '}$$

$$\underbrace {2 + 2 + 2 + 1}_{4\ \{1,2\}} = 7$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1}_{5\ \{1,2\}} = 7\ '}$$

$$\underbrace {2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1}_{6\ \{1,2\}} = 7$$

$$\color{red}{\underbrace {1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1}_{7\ \{1\}} = 7\ '}$$

After counting partitions marked with $\color{red} {red}$ and $\color{red} '$ we have, that:

$7$ is a prime number, that has $7$(prime number) partitions, that consists from prime numbers $\cup 1$ and has prime number of terms.

Are there any other prime numbers with similiar or weaker property(number of partitions!= initial number, but is a prime nubmer)?

P.S. If we exclude $1$ from $A$ we got $2 \ (3,2,2) \  (5,2) $ partitions which is prime number too.

P.P.S. We can get are a more stronger property if represent the partition as:

$$p=Tr(A*B)+r  $$

($r$ is a number of $1$ in partition. $A$ and $B$ is square diagonal matrices of order $n = |A\setminus{1}|$. The elements of matrix $A$ is elements of set $A\setminus{1}$ and $A_{ii}<A_{i+1,i+1}$. The elements of $B$ shows how many times corresponding matrix $A$ element occurs in partition.)

and selecting the partitions:

$$\tag 1 Part : \{ (r=0) \wedge (B=I_n) \wedge (A_{ii}\in P) \wedge (n \in P) \} \wedge |Part|\in P$$ where $P$ is a set of prime numbers and $I_n$ is identity matrix of order $n$

The seven fails here cause of $3+2+2$

If we add to $(1)$ another condition $|Part| = Tr(A*B)+r$ we will have:

$\tag 2 Part : \{ (r=0) \wedge (B=I_n) \wedge (A_{ii}\in P) \wedge (n \in P) \} \wedge |Part|\in P \wedge |Part| = Tr(A*B)+r$

It seems to mee that there is no prime numbers at all statisfy $(2)$. Any idea how to prove this or counterexamples?

Comment: Well... have *you* tried to see what happens with other primes?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez Nope, it's a few days of free code debugging with undefined result. So I decided to spent 5 minutes to post question, perhaps somebody already know something more about that and will satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: I found this question nice to think about, but likely involved to code up and look for solutions. (Also I'd be surprised if there were provable results, e.g. general families of such primes.)

Comment: Yes, if somebody could prove some intresting general statements on such numbers with/without using of $1$ in partition or post working property-testing code or plot $\phi (n)$ , where $n$ is a index of a prime and $\phi$ is number of partitions consisting only from primes and have prime number of terms. It would be really nice.

Comment: @igf, usually things go smoothlier if you have a concrete question in mind. Otherwise this becomes a fishing expedition... Notice that one can ask countably many questions like this.

Answer (score 5):

Make the list of the prime numbers which have a prime number of partitions with prime number of parts which are either one or prime, picked from the list of the first 150 primes:

```
In[3]:= 
Parallelize@ Select[
  Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[150]],
  Function[n, PrimeQ@ Length@ Select[
      IntegerPartitions[n, All, 
       Prepend[Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[n]], 1]],
      PrimeQ[Length[#]] &
      ]
   ]
  ]


Out[3]= {3, 7, 13, 23, 37, 71, 97, 109}
```

Same thing, but now not allowing parts to be equal to one:

```
In[4]:= 
Parallelize@ Select[
  Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[150]],
  Function[n, PrimeQ@ Length@ Select[
      IntegerPartitions[n, All, Prime /@ Range[PrimePi[n]]],
      PrimeQ[Length[#]] &
      ]
   ]
  ]


Out[4]= {7, 11, 13, 23, 47, 53, 73}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just checked, OEIS.org knows nothing about both of this sequences.